# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject

I'm getting this dreaded error trying to use Ninject with Web API. The full message is:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in
>   Ninject.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I've tried reinstalling pretty much everything, setting copy local = true, cleaning and rebuilding, restarting VS, deleting the suo, verifying binding redirects, etc etc etc. Nothing.

The one thing I don't fully understand is why everything is referencing v 5.2.3 when the error says it's trying to load 5.0.0. Could be a clue; I don't know. Here's the redirect from web.config. Thanks for any assistance.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.WebHost" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: what version of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost package you have, it should be 5.2.3 for System.Web.Http.WebHost 5.2.3 or should be 5.0.0 for System.Web.Http.WebHost 5.0.0 .

Comment: Indeed it is 5.2.3.

Comment: what about "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" & "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" are they both also 5.2.3. This error is possible when one of your old packages/assemblies are looking for version 5.0.0 of webhost.